# Android image button could not set to be not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image button and the following code in the click listener:

```
button v;
v.SetClickable(false);
if (some condition) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // do something
    }
}, 600);
v.SetClickable(true);
```

The problem is when I execute above code, I could still click the button v
during the 600 ms time slot. Any idea why? Is it refreshing problem?

Edit: None of the proposed solution works. My guess is this is something related to threading and postDelayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`v.setEnabled(false);`

instead of

`v.setClickable(false);`